# Is it possible to say "hi you back" in response to hi, if yes in what context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning

I have seen in  one of hollywood movies, one of the characters in response to "hi" answered back "hi you back". But I've found out this is not a common expression among English speakers. Please enlighten me with your incisive answers

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen in one of hollywood movies, one of the characters in response to "hi" answered back "hi you back"

If this were to be used, then *"'hi, you' back"* would really only make sense if the original greeting was *"hi, you"*.  Repeating someone directly in this way would generally be seen as mocking.  It could be friendly and joking, or it could be conveying that "hi, you" wasn't enough of an opening line of conversation--because there are bigger expectations.

For instance: imagine if someone hasn't been in touch for a long time, and should have been...but then suddenly shows up and sheepishly says "hi, you".  If the responder glares and says "'hi, you' back", the direct quote is to draw attention to how insubstantial the greeting was.  They've signaled they are displeased--and won't say any more until they're given a good excuse for why the person wasn't in touch sooner.

> But I've found out this is not much common expression among English speakers.

Nope.  If someone says something to you, there are much more normal ways to "send it back":

```
Person1: "Good morning!"
Person2: "Same to you!"

Person1: "Have a good afternoon!"
Person2: "You too!"
```

A more colloquial version would be "Back at ya!".  It could be used in the same circumstances, although it can sound a little like "trying to be too cool".  More often it would be used to return a compliment:

```
Person1: "You are the best!"
Person2: "Back at ya, bro!"
```

These could be used in a negative sense as well, to reflect back an insult:

```
Person1: "Go to hell!"
Person2: "Same to you!"
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough comment, please if possible answer this another question: Do we have this expression ' hi back' in English.

Comment: @Ahm10854 You might see the words sequentially if "hi" is being quoted.  ("Hey Mark!  She just texted me and said 'hi', what should I say?" => "You should just say 'hi' back.")  The quote marks might be omitted, and still understood.  But this is not how you would respond to someone who said "hi" to you... it would only apply in the way I said, where "'hi' back" is mocking or teasing by repeating what someone said and adding "back" to it.  As a general rule, don't do this unless you are sure you know what you're doing.